# how to reduce the size with imagemagick when the original file is too big

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I converted a 2.9M jpg  to a 20x20 using 8 as the quality. but that file's size is still 48k.

here is my command

```
  convert 238832c58dc3bc0b_29M.jpg -quality 8 -resize '20x20>' +repage 238832c58dc3bc0b_20x20.jpg
```

and after conveted, 238832c58dc3bc0b_20x20.jpg is 48k. I tried smalled size and quality, still 48k. it shouldn't be so big. it should be less than 10k. anybody know how to enhance it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -thumbnail instead of -resize or add -strip to your command.
Thumbnail removes the EXIF information apart from the color profile and strip removes the color profile as well.